# I got stuck with forge-viewer project based on typescript and react, can NOT add THREE.Mesh to viewer.impl.scene or ModelBuilder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have developed two different forge-viewer projects.
The first one is based on javascript. In that project, all added extensions just do what what I expect ! I can load models, change materials ( colors,textures,shaders) and add,scale,rotate and translate meshes.
BUT with my second forge-viewer project, based on typescript and react.
I totaly got stuck and need some help.The problem has to do with the way I import and use THREE in my project. Unfortunately, I really did NOT find any helpful example.
where someone describes the way how to use Forge-viewer,typescript,react and THREE ( e.g addMesh() )
ok, coming to the point, the problem is... I just cannot add an mesh into the scene !!!
not by using modelBuilder.addMesh( newMesh), and also NOT by using viewer.impl.scene.add( newMesh );
usually I get the three-error-message **object not an instance of THREE.Object3D**
even though my created THREE Object is for very sure an Object3D and is created as const mesh = THREE.Mesh();
ok, I already know, that this is error-message is a very clear indication, that there are 2 different three.js versions in play !!! As I know, the current Forge-Viewer – Version 7.3 use THREE.js Revision 7.1 and when I start my Project I get within google-devtools (in console-info)
the information THREE.WebGLRenderer 7.1 !!!
so , I use the right THREE version ...
BUT, the problems probably is, how I do import three !!!
In my project I have installed three by using
**npm install three0.71 –save**
and for the type-definitions
**npm install @types/three**
and
npm install @types/forge-viewer   (^7.32.2)

```
in index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v7.*" type="text/css"/>

<script language="JavaScript" src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v7.*"></script>
```

and in one of my extension written in typescript

```
import THREE from 'three';   // I do import THREE like this
                             // I already know, that this is the wrong way
                             // but please … how and from where do I have to import THREE 
            
export class TestExtensionPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel 
{
    thisJustDoesNotWork_01() 
    {
    this.grid = new THREE.GridHelper(size, density);
    this.viewer.impl.scene.add(this.grid);                                                                    this.viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true);
    }

    thisJustDoesNotWork_02()  // adding a mesh by modelBuilder 
    {
       const position = new THREE.Vector3(  xPos, yPos, zPos );
       const rotation = new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1);
       mesh.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(position,rotation,new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1));
       this.modelBuilder.addMesh(mesh);
    }

}
```

I really hope that someone will give me the right advice,
and again I already know, that it has to do with the import of THREE.js
I should not load or install it globally ... with npm install
but how and from where ????
THANK YOU very veryyyy MUCH in advance !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer actually bundles THREE.js (R71) in it so the quick answer is you should *never* import it yourself.

Importing another version of THREE.js will often cause the issue you describe because in R71, types of objects are checked like [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r71/src/core/Object3D.js#L321):

```js
if ( object instanceof THREE.Object3D ) {
```

While in newer versions it's checked like [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/Object3D.js#L323):

```js
if ( object && object.isObject3D ) {
```